# What is the syntax called that's used for syntax highlighting?

Tags: vim, syntax, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

My apologies if this is such a trivial question for most, but it is not readily obvious to me and I can't find an answer. I am trying to understand how to code syntax highlighting for vi, but the syntax used [for the syntax highlighting] eludes me. For example, I know that

```
syn match myNumber '\d\+'
hi myNumber ctermfg=blue
```

will highlight positive integers blue. What confuses me is the `'\d\+'` part. Playing around it seems that `\d` means digit and `\+` means several? But I have no idea what this syntax is called and thus can't find any documentation that could help me. I have only found links of people using it without explanation. I can probably decipher how

```
'[-+]\=\d[[:digit:]]*\.\d*[eE][\-+]\=\d\+'
```

means 'positive and negative numbers with decimals and exponents', but if I am to make more complex highlighting I don't know where to begin. Does anybody know of any documentation that I could use to learn this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called a "regular expression" or regex (or regexp) for short. See `:help pattern` and `:help usr_27.txt`. Also see [vimregex.com](http://www.vimregex.com/).